# Stored procedure does not return values

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my stored procedure returned in MySQL

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_content(content1)
BEGIN
SELECT content into content1
FROM page_content
WHERE id= 1;
/*END ;*/
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using following code to get values using stored procedure but its not returning anything, I just want to know if in case I am missing something. Here is my PHP code

```
$rs = mysql_query('CALL get_content(@content1)' ); 
$rs = mysql_query('SELECT @content1' ); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) 
{
    print_r($row); 
}
```

Please help me, thanks in advance

Sneha

Answer (score 0):

You need to use output parameter with SP.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE get_content(out content1 varchar(500)) 
BEGIN 
  SELECT content into content1 FROM page_content WHERE id= 1; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Call it by below method.

```
SET @content1 =NULL;

CALL `get_content`(@content1)

SELECT @content1;
```

Comment: Also: when procedure has one statement, the BEGIN-END and DELIMITER keywords can be omitted.